# telerik radgrid client side oncommand function is not defined, while using external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

we are using telerik grid. In our project usually we are not use any external js file, but one of my .ascx file is very slow when I edit the code so I decided to move all the script code into a new js file. But it is not working the oncommand function will not load it show "func_oncommand function is not defined" but that function definition is on the js file.

I am use the following line to import the js file

```
<script src="statutorysettings.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure the js file actually loads (e.g. check with the dev toolbar).
if it loads - then please paste here how you defined the radgrid

Comment: also, ensure you can call that function with some other event, like window.onload. Perhaps something is amiss with the concrete file/function (e.g., a typo) or there is some prior error that is causing the issue.